# Как перевести регулярное выражение с Java на Kotlin?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, kotlin

Подскажите, как лучше перевести следующую функцию с Java на Kotlin? Затруднение вызвали регулярные выражения:

```kotlin
private boolean filter(int size, String symbol, String sequence) {
    return ((size > 0 && !symbol.matches("\\d+"))
            || (size > 0 && !sequence.matches("[0-9]+"));
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите подробнее в самом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1319865/edit), что конкретно у вас вызвало затруднение. Если у вас возникла какая-то ошибка, то приложите текст этой ошибки в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что у строки в Котлин нет метода `.matches(String)`, но зато есть экстеншен `.matches(Regex)`, поэтому, вам нужно обернуть регулярку в конструктор `Regex()`:

```kotlin
text.matches(Regex(pattern))
```

Либо применить экстеншен `.toRegex()`:

```kotlin
text.matches(pattern.toRegex())
```